# 'this' in js and 'self' in python

Tags: data-structures

The code to create a Set class in JS from a lesson Ive been working on uses !this.has(element)...in the add method. In the next line, it doesnt use 'this'. I am wondering when I am supposed to use 'this' on its own as in the add method or use it as 'this.variableName' or simply use the variable name on its own. I have the same questions about the methods in data structure classes in python only with 'self'. At times it uses self.variableName and other times not. Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`self` in python and `this` in JS are equivalent.

Both mean the class instance. When using `self`, you are explicitly using the class property against another property that can have the same name. Eg:

```
class MyClass:
    value: int

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def sum(self, value):
        return self.value + value


myClass = MyClass(5)
print(myClass.sum(3))  # prints 8. In the sum method, self.value = 5 and value = 3.
```